# use path in FSTrigger plugin

Tags: plugins, jenkins, path, directory, monitor

I'm trying to Monitor folder on remote machine using jenkins plugin FSTrigger:

Trying this in path: 
wget http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/build/ --http-user=user --http-passwd=password

but jenkins tells me: 
Trying to monitor the folder 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/build/ --http-user=user --http-passwd=password'
The directory 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/build/ --http-user=user --http-passwd=password' doesn't exist.

is anyone can help me?

Regards
Karol

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use network file sharing protocol rather than web protocol(HTTP). For windows, I would use "\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\build" for path and make sure the folder is shared to the account running Jenkins. I'm not familiar with Linux... Just trying to help...